# Can you execute javascript code using node.js in conjunction with Forever?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, forever

Recently discovered [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and am completely in love with it. I like that I can run as many node.js instances as I like and can 
restart them all if need be.

When I run the javascript just through node.js I get bash where I can execute addition code if need be. My question is, can I execute code through Forever to execute on each node.js instance? So lets say I want to want to execute blah.doit(); on each one of my .js files running? Is that possible?

Can I do something like `forever -c blah.doit();`?

Comment: Dunno. Try it and tell us what happens.